# Почему дочь помогает маме НА кухне, а не В кухне?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Почему дочь помогает маме НА кухне, а не В кухне?

Answer (score 1):

**Дочь помогает маме на кухне.**

Здесь уж точно лучше сказать "на кухне", так как речь идет **не о комнате, а о процессе приготовления пищи.**

А вообще говоря, это **вечное противостояние предлогов В и НА**. Надо сказать, что вариант "на кухне" употребляется сейчас чаще, чем "в кухне" (5287: 2322).

**Управление в русском языке**
Автор Д. Э. Розенталь.«Издательство "Мир и Образование"», 2005.
© Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», 2017.

КУХНЯ — в / на кухню, в / на кухне (**вариант с предлогом НА возник под влиянием народной речи**). Я побежал в кухню рассказать бабушке всё, что видел и слышал (М. Г.); Нянька приходила на кухню поужинать (Кор.).

**Примеры:**

Никаких магнитофонов и проигрывателей, никаких пластинок, ни лент― ни **в кухне**, ни здесь я не заметил, даже радио выключено. [Виктор Астафьев. Обертон (1995-1996)]

Работа **на кухне** оказалась довольно нудной, никаких специализированных знаний там вовсе не требовалось. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)] 
...старшина-повар тем временем растапливал **на кухне** плиту. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

**Комментарий**

Трудно сказать, насколько существенным оказалось народное влияние, но  для моего слуха привычен только вариант "на кухне". Кухня ― это не просто комната с плитой, **это особенным образом организованное пространство** для приготовлении пищи, даже само слово *кухня* многозначное.